# Compiling Silverlight app sometimes fails due to Google Desktop

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, google-desktop

I am using Google Desktop on my machine.
When I want to build my Silverlight 4 app in Visual studio 2010, 1 out of 30 (roughly) times the build will fail saying "The "SubsetFontsSilverlight" task failed unexpectedly" and then it explains that the process cannot access a file in ...\obj\Debug\Fonts\Fonts.zip because it is being used by another process.
By trial-and-error I found out that if I close Google Desktop the problem goes away (I assume google desktop is currently indexing the file). The only way to solve this problem and compile my app again is to completely shut down Google Desktop. This is annoying. Does anybody have a workaround for this?
Thanks.
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's Google Desktop then you can exclude directories.  See this link:
http://desktop.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10117

Also, if it's not Google Desktop it could be an AntiVirus application that needs to exclude that directory.